# How to use img tag in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I write :

```
<img ng-src={{row.avatar}}>
```

It gives me the "url "as string in the path

It gives me the image source url as `url://my/image/path` due to "url" in the image path my image cannot be loaded.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

So try to get rid of it.

In your controller, create a function like:

```
$scope.removeUrl = function(url){
   return url.replace('url://', '');
}
```

and your ng-src like so:

```
ng-src="{{removeUrl(row.avatar)}}"
```